# Why can't I see access token in my logcat?

Tags: android, logcat, facebook-access-token

I am trying to see access_token in logcat but it's now showing up. Why?

```
private void updateUI() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Log.i("access_token", session.getAccessToken());

    if ( user != null) {
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
        greeting.setText(getString(R.string.hello_user, user.getFirstName()));
        accessToken.setText(session.getAccessToken());

    } else {
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
        greeting.setText(null);
        accessToken.setText(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: That happens when it is equal to "", are you sure it's not empty?

Comment: add something in front like "accesstoken"+ to check if it's being logged. Probably what Archie says, that there is no token yet.

Comment: when I concatenate String next to session.getAccessToken(), it showed up. Thanks.